# Не переводит объект в строку JsonSerializer

Tags: android, java

Использую библиотеку JACKSON. JsonDeserializer работает хорошо, переводит строку в объект. Ставил breakpoints по программе, в try catch ни где не перехватывает ошибки. По breakpoints выполняется следующим образом:

```
MyActivity --> String jaksonParse = MyJsonWrapper.getMyJson().writeValueAsString(jacksonObject); 

MyJsonWrapper --> module.addSerializer(Date.class, new JsonDateSerializer());
MyJsonWrapper --> jgen.writeString("/Date(" + date.getTime() + ")/");
MyActivity --> int s = 10;
```

После входа в MyJsonWrapper --> jgen.writeString("/Date(" + date.getTime() + ")/"), без всяких ошибок полностью выходит их try catch и выполняется дальше программа. Где я делаю не правильно. Здесь

```
   static class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>
  {
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {            
        jgen.writeString("/Date(" + date.getTime() + ")/");

    }
  }
```

или здесь

```
String jaksonParse = MyJsonWrapper.getMyJson().writeValueAsString(jacksonObject);
```

В программе объекты будут обрабатываться с разными полями.

Файлы программы:

MyJsonWrapper

```
package com.example;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.Version;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.module.SimpleModule;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonDeserializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer; 
import org.codehaus.jackson.smile.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.NullSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyJsonWrapper
{

public static ObjectMapper getMyJson()
{        
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));

    module.addSerializer(Date.class, new JsonDateSerializer());
    module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new JsonDateDeserializer());        

    mapper.registerModule(module);

    return mapper;
}

static class JsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>
{
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        String s = jp.getText().replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");

        if (s.equals("")) return null;

        boolean isDateBefore1970 = false;
        .........................................
        if (isDateBefore1970)
            return new Date(-Long.valueOf(s) - offset * 60 * 1000);
        else
            return new Date(Long.valueOf(s) + offset * 60 * 1000);

    }
  }

static class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>
{
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        try {            
        jgen.writeString("/Date(" + date.getTime() + ")/");            
        }   catch (JsonGenerationException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}    
}
```

MyActivity

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.example.JacksonObject;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String jacksonString = "{\"DateField\":\"/Date(-61283424600000)/\",\"StringField\":\"STRING_string\",\"DoubleField\":\"87.12345\",\"IntegerField\":\"387\"}";        

    try {           

        JacksonObject mailItems2 = MyJsonWrapper.getMyJson().readValue(jacksonString, JacksonObject.class);
        int a2 = 3;  //это просто так, что бы поставить точки!!!
        int  b = a2; //это просто так, что бы поставить точки!!!

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    try {
        JacksonObject jacksonObject = new JacksonObject();
        jacksonObject.DateField = new Date(41, 12, 18, 9, 30);
        jacksonObject.StringField = "Strinfffff";
        jacksonObject.DoubleField = 32.34344;
        jacksonObject.IntegerField = 456;

        String jaksonParse = MyJsonWrapper.getMyJson().writeValueAsString(jacksonObject);

        int a2 = 3;
        int  b = a2;

    }   catch (JsonGenerationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    int a = 3;
    int s = 10;
    s = s + a;
}
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. try-catch стоит у вас типизированный, попробуйте ловить `Throwable`
2. break-point не всегда может ловить, тем более в случаях когда код вызывается через рефлексию как в вашем случае. Понаставьте где можете логи LogCat `Log.d(TAG, "blah-blah");`
3. Посмотрите какое значение получает Date при попадании в сериализатор

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду пробывать!